# Excel PageSetup multiple sheets

Tags: excel, delphi

I have a Delphi routine which runs through a list of Excel files, opens them with MS Excel, iterates through the sheets setting the `PageSetup` for each sheet so all columns will fit on one page and then export all sheets to a single PDF.

```
MSApp := CreateOLEObject('Excel.Application');
doc := MSApp.WorkBooks.Open(fileOpenDialog1.FileName, False, True, EmptyParam, '', '',
  True, EmptyParam,  EmptyParam, EmptyParam, False, EmptyParam, False, False, EmptyParam);

MSApp.PrintCommunication := False;
doc.Sheets.Item[1].PageSetup.FitToPagesWide := 1;
if doc.Sheets.Count > 1 then
begin
  doc.Sheets.Item[1].Select(True);
  for i := 2 to doc.Sheets.Count do
  begin
    doc.Sheets.Item[i].Select(False);
    doc.Sheets.Item[i].PageSetup.FitToPagesWide := 1;
  end;
end;

doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(xlTypePDF, outPutFile, EmptyParam, False,
  EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, False, EmptyParam);

MSApp.PrintCommunication := True;
```

If there is only one sheet setting `FitToPagesWide` to 1 page works as expected. However, if there is more than one page and say the first page is too wide, the changes to the `PageSetup` for the first page do not stick and are lost by the time the file is exported.

Looking at the various examples online and the MS docs, I have been unable to find anything to suggest that the above should not work as expected or that there is some property that needs to be set in order to make `PageSetup` changes stick before moving on to the next sheet.

I could save each sheet to PDF individually and then merge the PDFs, but it seems to me that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: When you do the operation manually with Excel, does the "fit to page" setting works as you expect?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When your code doesn't work as expected? When you have one sheet that cant fit to single page or when you have multiple sheets in one file?

Comment: I had this issue, even posted a question about it.  Try setting the `PageSetup.Zoom := false` before setting `FitToPagesWide`.

Comment: @fpiette - you can't do the operation manually AFAIK (although I am no Excel guru). In Excel you have to go to the backstage choose print and then select the "Fit All Columns on One Page". From print you can also choose to print the entire workbook with these settings. However, if you choose save as and select pdf, I think you can only save the current sheet not the workbook.

Comment: @SilverWarior - If there is a single sheet it works fine. If there are multiple sheets and one of those sheets has columns that will extend on to a new page that is where I am having the problem. The setting of properties for pageSetup as you iterate through each sheet seems to be lost when you move on to the next sheet.

Comment: @JohnEasley - I've tried that, but it makes no difference other than to throw up an error. Zoom is automatically set to false when you set FitToPagesWide. Also, if setting Zoom in code, false is not an acceptable value. It expects an integer value, hence the error.

Comment: @MarkWilliams what version of Excel and Delphi are you using?

Comment: @JohnEasley - Office 365 (latest). Delphi 10.4

Comment: @MarkWilliams Looking at your code in case when you have multiple Sheets in your document you first go and change `Select` property of the first one to `True` and only then you loop through the rest of the sheets setting `Selec`t property of each to `False` and then changing `pageSetup.FitToPagesWide` to `1`. I'm guessing that messing with this `select` property that you do only in case of multiple sheets in document might be causing your problems.

Comment: @MarkWilliams As for changing `Zoom` property to `false` as JohnEasley suggested I suggest you set `Zoom` property to `0`. If Zoom property is intended to act as Boolean do note that in case of numerically represented Boolean value value of 0 always represents `False` and any non-zero value represents `True`. And if `Zoom` property is intended to represent Zoom level, then setting it to 0 will most likely mean that Zoom is disabled because otherwise excel would have to work with `Division by Zero` when trying to set proper zoom level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you observe is caused improper use of [`Application.PrintCommunication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.printcommunication) property. All changes to `PageSetup` are cached from the moment when you set it to `False` until those changes are commited by setting the property value back to `True`. But you do that after exporting the workbook via `ExportAsFixedFormat`. The solution is simple:

- either don't use `PrintCommunication`
- or set its value to `True` *before* the export

Now why the first worksheet is exported in the layout as you expected? I can only guess that it's because it was already saved with width shrinking configured on the first worksheet only:
[image: Page layout]

Here are some further observations:

- There's no need to select/deselect a worksheet before/after changing its `PageSetup`.
- There's no need to handle the first worksheet as a special case. You can set them all up in a single loop.
- I would preemptively set `FitToPagesTall` to `0` (or `False`) in case the worksheet has configured height shrinking.

Of course the recommended way to perform multiple changes to `PageSetup` is within `PrintCommunication := False` block. With the above applied you get:

```
procedure ExportWorkbookAsPDF(const InputFileName, OutputFileName: string);
var
  App, Workbook, PageSetup: OleVariant;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  App := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    App.DisplayAlerts := False;
    App.Interactive := False;
    Workbook := App.Workbooks.Open(FileName := InputFileName, UpdateLinks := False,
      ReadOnly := True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended := True);
    try
      App.PrintCommunication := False;
      for Index := 1 to Workbook.Sheets.Count do
      begin
        PageSetup := Workbook.Sheets.Item[Index].PageSetup;
        PageSetup.FitToPagesWide := 1;
        PageSetup.FitToPagesTall := 0;
      end;
      App.PrintCommunication := True;
      Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(xlTypePDF, OutputFileName);
    finally
      Workbook.Close(False);
    end;
  finally
    App.Quit;
  end;
end;
```

In your original code you use [`Workbook.Sheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheets) collection to iterate over all *sheets* in a workbook, which includes also charts. To apply `PageSetup` to *worksheets* only use [`Workbook.Worksheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.worksheets) collection. See [Worksheets vs Sheets](https://www.excelhowto.com/worksheets-vs-sheets/) for more information.